# Which diode would I use to prevent over charging a battery?

Tags: batteries, diodes, battery-charging

For my school science project, I need to prevent overcharging my 1.2v rechargeable batteries. I have two which adds up to 2.4 volts. I need to make sure my batteries don't overcharge with my solar power. Should I use a diode? Should I use a resistor? Should I use a charge controller? Please link possibilities from Amazon.com so I can buy them! Project is on a tight deadline!

Comment: You use a charge controller, not a diode.

Comment: Describe your school science project and specify exactly why you can't use a standard charger. Are you saying you can afford to buy the batteries but are unable to afford a charger?

Comment: If you put two 'normal' diodes in series, the combined forward voltage will be 2 x 0.6V = 1.2V approximately.

Comment: In line with PlasmaHH's comment, please provide a circuit schematic of how you plan to use diodes to prevent overcharge. If you use diodes in parallel to limit the charge voltage, please provide a source for this technique. That way you will know who not to believe the next time you're doing research.

Comment: The symbols of Zener and Schottky diodes are similar but your probably thinking of Zener diodes as they can very roughly regulate voltage. However this is not considered a safe method to prevent overcharging so you'll need a dedicated IC that manages charging. You haven't specified what type of battery it is.

Comment: Well, Im using https://www.instructables.com/id/4-Solar-Battery-Charger/ and it says I need a blocking diode. I can get a charge controller but I was wondering if a diode would be cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

TWo silicon power diodes and a series power R to handle a slow overnight charge current to 1.4V max will be ok if you verify the values with us.

[**Read**](http://www.powerstream.com/NiMH.htm) for more details on NiMH

Answer (score 1):

For overcharging protection, you don't need a diode at all. Just a resistor to limit the current. Depending on your power supply, calculate Imax = V/R and choose R to slow charge your NiMh or NiCd, usual C/10 (where C is rated capacity).

Eg. for 2000mAh and 10V supply, will choose to slow charge at 200mA and this means 10/0.2 = 50ohms.

The power of your resistor needs to be R*I2 = 50*0.2*0.2 = 2W

A diode will protect you for reverse supply voltage, so a low Vf will be the best choice. Choose a Schottky where Vf is minimum at desired current, your case 0.2A. The power supply must provide then initial Vs + Vf.

PS. In above calculations, your charging resistor needs to be well over 2W but anyhow, this will be just loosed power (heating up laboratory), translating in quite low efficiency.

A dedicated charger circuit, will be able (more or less) to approach much more efficiency and this means transferring as much energy to your battery. Never mention many other benefits (for your battery chemistry and life) while using it.